# Split string in Perl

Tags: perl

Ho to split string for example like this:

$string ="AvsdsldsdFsdsdsvcFdfddf"

I'd like to split it on groups, which all of them will have to signs. After that, I'd like to put this groups into an array.

Comment: Define "groups". What is the result you want from this string? Can you provide other specific input->output examples? Your question is currently not very clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regular expression will match every group of two chars:

```
$string ="AvsdsldsdFsdsdsvcFdfddf";    
@myarray = $string =~ /(..)/g;
```